# Couldn't update list item in SP 2013 using Rest

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, updatelistitems

I am trying to update a field in my list but I keep getting this error:

> "A type named 'SP.Data.ttcuAnnListItem' could not be resolved by the
>   model. When a model is available, each type name must resolve to a
>   valid type"

This is the code:

```
    function UpdateListItem(listName,itemId,titleVal){
    var itemType = GetItemTypeForListName(listName);
    var item = {
        "__metadata": { "type": itemType },
        "Title": titleVal    
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items("+itemId+")",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
            "If-Match": "*"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Success');
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("Error");
        $("#title1").html(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
}
```

And the code for the GetItemTypeForListName function :-

```
// Get List Item Type metadata
function GetItemTypeForListName(name) {
    return "SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.split(" ").join("").slice(1) + "ListItem";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello if you only want ListItemEntityTypeFullName once the you get the name from browser by browsing with below endpoint

```
your siteurl/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('ttcuAnn')?$select=ListItemEntityTypeFullName
```

or if you want to get in code below is the script

```
function getItemTypeList(listName){
return jQuery.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('" + listName + "')?$select=ListItemEntityTypeFullName",
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                'Accept': "application/json;odata=verbose",
            },
    data: JSON.stringify(""),
});
}    

function UpdateListItem(listName,itemId,titleVal,itemTypeList){
//var itemType = GetItemTypeForListName(listName);
var item = {
    "__metadata": { "type": itemTypeList},
    "Title": titleVal    
};

$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items("+itemId+")",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    data: JSON.stringify(item),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
        "If-Match": "*"
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert('Success');
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert("Error");
    $("#title1").html(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
}

getItemTypeList('ttcuAnn').then(function(data){UpdateListItem(listName,itemId,titleVal,data.d.ListItemEntityTypeFullName);},function(data){alert(''call failed!)})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to confirm that the Metadata Type is in fact `SP.Data.ttcuAnnListItem`.

You can do this easily by performing a Rest API GET request on the `\items` endpoint. In the response you will see the correct type name. What you POST will need to match this. You can check this directly in the browser for a specific list using this url format `https://<sitename>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(<**ListName**>)/items`

Or, If you wish to leave the function generic, you could update your `GetItemTypeForListName` function to actually perform the GET request in order to parse it and return the correct type name.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I am new to Rest can you please tell me how to check this directly in the browser?

Comment: Please see my updated answer, and please upvote or mark as answer if it is helpful for you.

Comment: The url doesn't redirect me to the list, I also tried this method before posting but it is also not working:                                                                                              function getItemTypeForListName(listTitle)
{
  return executeJson({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/?$select=ListItemEntityTypeFullName",
    method: 'GET'
  }).then(function(data){
       return data.d.ListItemEntityTypeFullName;
  });  
}

Comment: Also what is surprising is that I am using the same function to read items from the list and it's working fine, just when I update them I get the error